# EOL character in Linux and Windows

Tags: python, telnet

I'm writing a simple script, that just connects to telnet port, listens everything on it, staying connected and when some string, for example '123' appears, script do something. 
I use tn.read_until("123", 2), but when '123' appears, script just disconnects. How to make it stay online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put tn.read_until("123", 2) in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 21))
s.listen(1)
conn = s.accept()
run = True
while run==True:
    data = conn.recv(1000)
    if data == '123':
        #do something
    else:
        #do something
conn.close()
```

is this what you want..

Comment: So, what happens when the data that arrive are "123\r\n"?